# Terminal: Where is the shell start-up file?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, virtualenvwrapper

I'm following a tutorial called [Starting a Django 1.4 Project the Right Way](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/10/24/starting-a-django-14-project-the-right-way/), which gives directions on how to use virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper, among other things.

There's a section that reads:

> If you're using pip to install packages (and I can't see why you wouldn't), you can get both virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper by simply installing the latter.
>
> ```
>    $ pip install virtualenvwrapper
> ```
>
> After it's installed, add the following lines to your shell's start-up file (.zshrc, .bashrc, .profile, etc).
>
> ```
>    export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
>    export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/directory-you-do-development-in
>    source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
> ```
>
> Reload your start up file (e.g. source .zshrc) and you're ready to go.

I am running Mac OSX, and don't know my way around the Terminal too well. What exactly does the author mean by `shell's start-up file (.zshrc, .bashrc, .profile, etc)`? Where do I find this file, so that I can add those three lines?

Also, what does he mean by `reload your start up file (e.g. source .zshrc)`?

I would appreciate a detailed response, specific to OSX.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You're probably using `bash` so just add these 3 lines to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
$ cat >> ~/.bash_profile
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/directory-you-do-development-in
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
^D
```

where `^D` means you type <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (EOF).

Then either close your terminal window and open a new one, or you can "reload" your `.bash_profile` like this:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: A slight quibble: `.profile` can be read by many different shells, some of which may not recognize `source` as a more-readable synonym for `.`. Use `. /usr/local/bin/virtualenwrapper.sh` instead for the third line. Or, put those three lines in `.bash_profile` instead.

Comment: And if .bash_profile already exists, .profile is not read at all.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I've updated the answer to explicitly use `.bash_profile` rather than `.profile`.

Comment: I'm runing windows 7 and I have cmd.exe So where I add these lines?

Comment: @UFM: you should probably install [cygwin](http://cygwin.com) so that you can use a bash shell on Windows.

Comment: I tried this after `pip install virtualenvwrapper` but I have this error when I reload the `.bash_profile` : `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 7):

If you use bash, it usually means `~/.bash_profile`.

In Terminal and iTerm new shells are login shells by default, so `~/.bashrc` is not read at all. If instructions written for some other platform tell you to add something to `.bashrc`, you often have to add it to `.bash_profile` instead.

If both `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile` exist, only `.bash_profile` is read. `.profile` is also read by other shells, but many of the things you'd add to `.bash_profile` wouldn't work with them.

From /usr/share/doc/bash/bash.html:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.
>
> [...]
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists.

Answer (score 2):

I have Anaconda install, so I add these 3 lines to ~/.bash_profile

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Documents/Python
source /Users/Username/anaconda3/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

and then reload profile by:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

I use an approach that I think is easy to maintain.
It also works well if you sometimes use Ubuntu systems, however I will be sure to address the OP's OSX requirement in my answer.

1. Create a `.aliases` file with your alias(es) in your home directory, e.g. `~/.aliases`
2. Execute this file from your `.bashrc` file (this is executed each time for a new shell process) with `source ~/.aliases`.  This is all you would actually need to do for Ubuntu btw.
3. On OSX call `.bashrc` from your `~/.profile` file, i.e. have `~/.bash_profile` contain: `source ~/.bashrc`