# Virtualenvwrapper.sh lssitepackages command not working

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to get to grips with Python virtual environments and have followed a few excellent tutorials such as [simononsoftware](http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/) and [IAmZed](http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/) which were recommended in an answer to another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844869/comprehensive-beginners-virtualenv-tutorial)

However I am having some problems with virtualenvwrapper. I am reading the docs [here](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

I believe I have installed virtualenvwrapper correctly. When I type

```
localhost:workspace brendan$ which virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I receive the below. **Note**: This is outside my virtual environment.

```
/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

However when I enter my virtual environment via

```
localhost:workspace brendan$ source virt_env/Credibility/bin/activate
```

and type

```
(Credibility)localhost:workspace brendan$ lssitepackages
```

I receive

```
-bash: lssitepackages: command not found
```

I have also installed virtualenvwrapper inside my Credibility virtualenv but the command still does not work.

This is my `yolk -l` output from within the Credibility Virtualenv

```
(Credibility)localhost:workspace brendan$ yolk -l
Django          - 1.5.1        - active 
Python          - 2.7.1        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload)
SQLAlchemy      - 0.8.2        - active 
distribute      - 0.7.3        - active 
nose            - 1.3.0        - active 
pip             - 1.4          - active 
setuptools      - 0.9.7        - active 
stevedore       - 0.10         - active 
virtualenv-clone - 0.2.4        - active 
virtualenv      - 1.10.1       - active 
virtualenvwrapper - 4.1.1        - active 
wsgiref         - 0.1.2        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7)
yolk            - 0.4.3        - active 
(Credibility)localhost:workspace brendan$
```

My suspicion where I might be going wrong. In the [docs](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) it says to

> First, some initialization steps. Most of this only needs to be done
>   one time. **You will want to add the command to source
>   /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh to your shell startup file,
>   changing the path to virtualenvwrapper.sh depending on where it was
>   installed by pip.**

I was not really sure how to do this so I followed the instructions in another SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101559/terminal-where-is-the-shell-start-up-file)

```
localhost:documents brendan$ cd workspace/
localhost:workspace brendan$ pwd
/Users/brendan/documents/workspace
localhost:workspace brendan$ cat >> ~/.profile
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Users/brendan/documents/workspace
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
localhost:workspace brendan$ source ~/.bash_profile
localhost:workspace brendan$
```

I thought this would have fixed it, as you can see I reloaded my Terminal window, I also restarted it. However unlike installing a package, this gave me no feedback as I completed each of the steps and I think it might be causing the problem.

Can anyone see an issue here or is there another problem I am not seeing?

Thanks for the help

Setup: Mac OSX 10.7.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should instal virtualenvwrapper outside of your virtual environment, not inside it. Then adjust your profile accordingly:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/documents/workspace
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

*You have the wrong path for `PROJECT_HOME`*

Next, as you have done source the file.

Finally:

```
$ mkvirtualenv foo
...
(foo)$ lsvirtualenv
```

Doing so with the `mkvirtualenv` command ensures that the correct files are executed, which will add the commands with the right paths in your virtual environment. Next time you want to work on a virtual envronment, you should use the `workon` command, as in:

```
 $ workon foo
```

This will make sure the paths are set up correctly along with the virtualenv wrapper specific commands.

Comment: I'm not sure why but when i first tried this it would not work on any of my existing projects, but would work when i created a new virtual environment.