# Command on terminal startup

Tags: macos, terminal, startup

What I am trying to do is have my current ASCII ART appear on start up as well as have *ls* run so I can see my directories. I assume this is going to be a script that I will have to do so if anyone can point me in the right direction to get started that would be awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll most likely want to add whatever commands display your ASCII art and `ls` to the end of the ~/.bash_profile file. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101559/terminal-where-is-the-shell-start-up-file).

In other words, open the `/Users/$USER/.bash_profile` file in a text editor (or create it if it doesn't exist) and put `ls` at the end of the file on its own line.

This startup shell file is also called `.profile` or `.bashrc` on other linux/unix systems. More information on this behavior is available [here](http://stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others). The scripting language for the file is [bash](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html).